# Using Special Characters in Java (using primitive char)

Tags: java, arrays, char, special-characters, primitive

I'm basically trying to build a random password generator in Java. I'm trying to build it using a `char` array, basically:

```
char[] password = new char[8]
```

I want to be able to include "special" characters in this array (such as `@`, `$`, `*`, etc). Can these characters be placed in a char array, and if so, how?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Char` type in Java. There is `char` or `Character`.

Comment: Also yes, characters are written with `'` like `'a'` so you can place them in array just like you normally place any element.

Comment: If you are generating passwords, then use `SecureRandom` instead of simple `Random`.  It does make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put characters in array inline

```
char[] password = {'@', '$', '*'};
```